# Backbone View Templates - Storing Them As External Files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates, backbone.js

I've been tinkering around with Backbone.js and wanted to know if there is possible to load View templates from external files.  I've been using Underscore.js's micro template solution and including all my templates inside my HTML document has been bothering me.

I wanted to know if there is a standard way of doing this.  Is there any good practice I should follow?

Thank you all for you time and help :-)

Answer (score 0):

For all the template libraries that compile strings to javascript, with a little code in the header, each template could be stored in a separate file and exported through a common `windows.myTemplates` object or similar. The code would just evaluate the given string (the actual template), and bind the result to the windows object to make it available to other scripts. This way each template would be it's own script and would be accesses through a global object like `windows.myTemplates.someTemplate`.

That does not mean this is a good idea; unless you have many and/or big templates that are loaded very seldom, the normal goal is to minimize the roundtrips to the server, which is the exact opposite of what you are doing. Server-side, things are a bit different, but I'm assuming you're talking client side (based on your question).

There are fancier ways of pulling things in only when needed (google "javascript AMD", require.js and similar), but those are a bit more challenging to get started with.